# knockout binding how to remove an attribute

Tags: knockout.js

Let's say I have an Html element

```
<element testattribute='a'></element>
```

I know I can pass the value of testattribute using a binding like this:

```
<element data-bind="attr: { testattribute: 'a'}></element>
```

But how can I completely remove this attribute through the binding.
So if the original value was

```
 <element testattribute: 'a'></element>
```

my end result should be

```
<element></element>
```

Comment: There's actually the _need_ to provide a way to serve empty attributes like `alt`. Some of them define the way assistive technology and maybe crawlers interpret your code, check https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H67.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `attr` [binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) in KO will actually remove the attribute if the value is `false`, `null`, or `undefined`.  So, if you bind against an observable and then set it to one of those values (not empty string), then the attribute will be removed.

Comment: Thank you. I had actually tried it with empty string and to your point, needed a false or a null.

Answer (score 3):

you should do this ternary inline because form not accepts several checked radio button and it will ignore the knockout comments so none would be checked to avoid do like:

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="attr:{'checked':($data.amount > 0) ? 'checked' : false}" id="q156" name="foo" value="positive" />
```

this will set accurate!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional binding to show the element

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

What you could do, is have two versions of the element, one with the attr binding, and one without, and use the following code to figure out what should be displayed for that particular binding.

```
<!-- ko if: someExpressionGoesHere -->
        <element data-bind="attr: { testattribute: 'a'}></element>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: someExpressionGoesHere == false -->
        <element></element>
<!-- /ko -->
```